# Object dimensions change after filling with the Shape Builder Tool/Paint Bucket Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I already wrote in Adobe forum about this issue (https://forums.adobe.com/message/8339546#8339546) and tried all suggestions to solve this problem, but still nothing… I will try to explain my problem as clearly as possible here.

I’m using Mac and newest Illustrator CC version (19.2.0).

So the problem is that when I fill an object with a Shape Builder Tool/Paint Bucket Tool that object dimensions always changes. You can see an example in a picture (it's just an example, I don't use shape builder for simple objects like this circle, but for more complicated objects it's very useful). I created 35x35mm circle and used Shape Builder Tool 3 times in a row and each time I got diffrent results.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? This is very important to me, because I just can't work like this.

It would be very helpful to get an answer. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The problem is a lot harder to reproduce when using inches. Sadly it seems to be some kind of rounding error. There are many small rounding errors when working with mm in Illustrator. I prefer using InDesign whenever I can.

Answer (score 1):

All right, when creating a shape in Illustrator with exact dimensions everything is OK. Once a stroke is added, it can affect the object's total dimension depending on the stroke's parameters:

[image]

1. 35x35mm circle filled without a stroke
2. 35x35mm circle with a 0.5mm **stroke aligned to inside**, no fill.
3. 35x35mm circle with a 0.5mm **stroke aligned to center**, no fill.
4. 35x35mm circle with a 0.5mm **stroke aligned to outside**, no fill.

Now when these objects are expanded or edited with live painting / shape shifter, the total dimensions will be:

1. 35 x 35 mm
2. 35 x 35 mm
3. 35.5 x 35.5 mm
4. 36 x 36 mm

In conclusion, if you want the total dimension to remain intact, use strokes that are aligned to the inside.

Comment: I've just done the same thing. This is that I get:

1. 34,999  x 35,003 mm
2. 34,999  x 35,003 mm
3. 34,999  x 35,003 mm
4. 34,999  x 35,003 mm

No matter what stroke posizion I choose (or completely without stroke) the results are always the same. Also they are not 35x35 mm and different than yours.